# Send button in Contact form stopped working

Tags: button, blogger, send

Send button in Contact form stopped working in Blogger

I have two separate Contact form gadgets in my blog. All of a sudden the Send button stopped working. After entering all the fields, when I  click on it nothing happens. Other people have told me the same thing.
I didn't change anything. Neither of them work. One is available in the desktop menu bar as Contact and the other is at the bottom in the footer. They don't work in mobile or desktop.
I deleted the code and recreated but Send button still not working. It is the same code that worked before.
 Please help. My website is www.tutorhubllc.com.

I am unable to paste the code here at I am using

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contact form gadget does not contain a form element.

Contact form should have a [form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) element with a proper action attribute. The form tag is used to collect user input and specifies where to send the data when submitting.

Try to add another fresh gadget from your control panel layout.

Comment: Thanks.. Right now all seems to be working but I have noticed several glitches. Not sure if anyone else has any issues. Things stop working, blogger hangs up often...

Comment: What are these issues? You can open new questions.